# How to calculate Fractal dimension from DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem, topography

I have a digital elevation model of a sea floor topography, and I have already creat TIN, shp, ras of this zone (only X, Y, Z(depth))

To calculate the topography complexity, I think fractal dimension (2D and 3D)index is important to my research.

I use ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.